# Pymongo Aggregate with Group and Push

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a collection in the form as below:

```
UserName | Device | Device Rights
```

I have multiple documents for each user with different devices.
I am trying to aggregate and store the data grouped by user in the collection. To get output as below:

```
UserName | Device | Device Rights| Device 2 | Device 2 Rights...
```

Using the below code in Pymongo:

```
cur = data1_dbh.access_data 

cur.aggregate=([
        {'$group': {
     '_id': "$username",
     'accessdetails':{'$push': {'device':"$device_id", 'accesstype':"$access_type"}},
}}
    
])
x=cur.aggregate

for i in x:
    print(i)
```

But I get a single line of code as output. What am i missing..

```
{'$group': {'_id': '$username', 'accessdetails': {'$push': {'device': '$device_id', 'accesstype': '$access_type'}}}}
```

Comment: Its giving correct output https://mongoplayground.net/p/XZn7e-FE32p

Comment: am running this in jupyter.. not sure why its not working..

Comment: Share your sample documents

Comment: Have resolved this. Thanks